# Mouse not working with i3

Tags: mouse, i3

I have a Rapoo mouse. It is working with gnome but not with i3. Why is it so?

[image]

Comment: can you elaborate on "works" and "does not work" ?

Comment: No click, no movement. Nano usb

Comment: Check with `xev` and optionally `xinput` what kind of events you get from the mouse.